# How to make default 'selected' option in select tag a parameter of a nested attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to make it so the default value shown in a select field in a form is a user parameter, but the problem is the parameter is a nested attribute. I am unsure how to go about it, and so far I haven't found anything through google.

Here is what I have:

```
<%= f.select :gender, options_for_select(['Male', 'Female']), { prompt: '--select gender--', selected: params[profile: [:gender]] }, { class: 'form-control' } %>
```

To clarify, `Profile` is a nested attribute of `User`. They have an one to one association (`Profile` belongs to `User`).

I have also tried just putting `selected: params[:gender]` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Here are the user_params (in User controller):

```
def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(
        :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
        profile_attributes: [
            :user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :date_of_birth,
            :occupation, :education, :city, :post_code, :country
        ]
      )
end
```

And the edit and update methods (also User controller):

```
# Edit profile page
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Patch method for updating profile
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Here is the view the form is on, users/edit.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Edit profile') %>
<section>
  <h3 class="pink-text"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> EDIT PROFILE</h3>
  <%= render 'form' %>
</section>
```

users/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4>Account information</h4>
      <%= f.label :email, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "john@example.com" %>
      </div>
      <%= f.label :password, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "A-Z,a-z,0-9" %>
      </div>
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm password", class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Confirm password" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Render profile form -->
    <%= f.fields_for :profile, @user.profile do |profile| %>
      <% render 'profile_fields', f: profile %>
    <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %> <!-- form_for @user -->
```

And users/_profile_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :first_name, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'First Name' %>
  </div>

  <%= f.label :last_name, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Last Name' %>
  </div>

  <%= f.label :gender, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <%= f.select :gender, options_for_select(['Male', 'Female']), { prompt: '--select gender--', selected: @selected }, { class: 'form-control' } %>
  </div>

  <%= f.label :date_of_birth, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <%= f.date_field :date_of_birth, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <%= f.label :occupation, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <%= f.text_field :occupation, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Occupation" %>
  </div>

   <%= f.label :city, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
     <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "City" %>
   </div>

   <%= f.label :post_code, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
     <%= f.text_field :post_code, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Post code" %>
   </div>

    <%= f.label :country, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.country_select :country, { priority_countries: ["AU", "US", "GB", "CA", "NZ"], include_blank: true }, { class: 'form-control' } %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the controller action for the view where you have `<%= f.select :gender, options_for_select(['Male', 'Female']), { prompt: '--select gender--', selected: params[profile: [:gender]] }, { class: 'form-control' } %>`?

Comment: Okay, added it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call params from your view, first set the value you want to display in the controller (with a *class instance variable*) and then use it in your view.

In controller:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @selected = user_params[:profile][:gender]
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
    profile: [
      :user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :date_of_birth,
      :occupation, :education, :city, :post_code, :country
    ])
end
```

Notice that `user_params` was also updated (changed `profile_attributes` to `profile`).

In view:

```
<%= f.select :gender, options_for_select(['Male', 'Female']), { prompt: '--select gender--', selected: @selected }, { class: 'form-control' } %>
```

Comment: I get an error from this: "ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#edit"

Comment: I updated the answer (i missed the array in `user_params`). Can you also share your `index.html.erb` (or the view where are you calling the `edit` method)?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. :/ I added the view above.

Comment: Your _strong parameters_ method `user_params` needs to be updated (change `profile_attributes` to `profile`). I updated the answer to show this (and also reflect changes on `edit`).

Comment: Hi unfortunately I'm still getting an error same error along with "param is missing or the value is empty: user"

Comment: In which line is the error? Could you show the complete error?